# Handling CLOBs with SQLite JDBC adapter

Tags: java, sqlite, clob

When I look at the SQLite DB it says the type is CLOB, however, when I try to use the getClob method I see the following....

> "not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver"

So should I be using a String then? Should I just use UTF-8 or what type of encoding should be used? Value is HTML with the possible embedded picture.

Answer (score 0):

For now the answer appears to be using a String.

I tried this and the pics rendered in Swing. Better answer gets the check.